# How to solve: T(n)=T(n^0.5)+n^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I prove the following?

> T(n) = T(n<sup>0.5</sup>) + n<sup>2</sup> = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

I tried to open the function declaration step by step but it got complicated and I got stuck!

Comment: Might be worth sharing your attempt in case there's something obvious you might have missed and another set of eyes can spot. .

Comment: This would be a better fit for the computer science stack overflow: https://cs.stackexchange.com/.  (Yeah, all the different websites can be a bit confusing). Also, it'd be worth looking at how to ask  a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question's okay, but you could definitely elaborate more on what you've tried and why you think you're stuck.

Comment: Also I think you're missing a base case here since T(1) doesn't work out to a valid expression

Comment: @apokryfos, formally, that's true, but because this is CS, we know that `T(k)` is a constant for any given `k`, so in practice we can say `T(2) = c`, where `c` is some constant, and because this is theta notation, it's equivalent to say that `T(2) = 1`

Comment: @Elliott I'm just saying because in many cases of homework questions the base case is crafted in such a way to "make the numbers work out easily" so might give a hint in what path to take to a solution.

Comment: @apokryfos, actually, I was wrong: For this problem we don't even need a base case at all (if one was given then it could *change* the function, but the function is still complete without it). It was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 3):

We can expand the expression to:

> T(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>1</sup> + n<sup>1/2</sup> + n<sup>1/4</sup> + ...

Sum the geometric sequence:

> T(n) = 2 * n<sup>2</sup>

So:

> T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)